# Trouble Getting Value From API Hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am making an API call and receiving the following response:

```
{
   "id": "http://www.google.com/",
   "shares": 8262403,
   "comments": 827
}
```

When I do:

```
api_call["shares"]
```

It just returns

```
shares
```

...and I want the value of "shares" so I have the share count. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) :

```
require 'json'

str = '{
   "id": "http://www.google.com/",
   "shares": 8262403,
   "comments": 827
}'

JSON.parse(str)['shares'] # => 8262403
```

> When I do `api_call["shares"]`, It just returns `shares`.

This is because your response comes as a `String`. Now on which you are calling [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method. The docs `str[match_str] → new_str or nil` says - **If a match_str is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string.**

```
str['shares'] # => shares
```

This happened as per the documentation,as I mentioned. Your response string has a substring `shares`, which is being returned as a method call `String#[]`, in `str['shares']` call.